# OO design vs static classes in java and concurrency exploitation

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, concurrency

I have 7-8 callable classes which makes use of some similar functionality and also read on some same list and HashMap.
So I created a static class containing all the functionality as static functions and static list and hashMap.

Now, I have some queries :

1.) Is it a wrong practice to have static classes in java as my senior scold me over using a static class and rather asked me to convert it into a singleton class.

But static classes are faster than singleton. Isn't it ?

2.) Is it a bad design to have a reference to a static/non-static method to obtain some data like a list inside a call method (in a thread) or to perform some task?

Does it violate thread safety or parallelism as my senior said ? And ask me to have the list inside the thread class as private member.

But isn't that bad use of memory as other 6-7 thread classes makes use of the same list to read only.

3.) How can I improve the OO design with improvement in performance as well.

A sample code would look like this :

```
public class StaticClass {
    private static List<String> ListOne;
    private static List<String> listTwo;
    private static HashMap<String, String> hMap;

    static{
        //initialize list and maps by reading from file
    }


    public static List<String> getListOne() {
        return ListOne;
    }
    public static List<String> getListTwo() {
        return listTwo;
    }
    public static HashMap<String, String> gethMap() {
        return hMap;
    }

    public static void commonMethodOne(){

    }

    public static String commonMethodTwo(){

        }

    public static String[] commonMethodThree(){

    }

}
```

```
public class CallableThread implements Callable<String>{

    public String call(){

        HashMap<String, String> mapTask = StaticClass.gethMap();
        List<String> taskOne =StaticClass.getListOne();

        for(String temp : taskOne){
            //do what you are suppose to do
        }
        for(String key : mapTask.keySet()){
            //do what you are supposed to do
        }
        return "Done with CallableThread";
    }
}
```

Comment: No "senior" person would recommend a Singleton.   I see no advantage to making this static or singleton.  If you have mutable shared data you'd better be mindful about synchronizing it correctly.  Looks to me like you're worried about the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2):

A method like this is a terrible idea (poor naming and failure to follow the Java coding standards aside):

```
public static List<String> getListOne() {
    return ListOne;
}
```

You return a mutable reference, so anyone who gets this List can modify its contents as they see fit.  Private is no longer private.

If you must return a reference to a private List or data structure (no reason to do so that I can see), you should either make it immutable or return a copy.

```
public static List<String> getListOne() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(ListOne);
}
```

You've got mutable shared data without any synchronization of any kind, so this class is not thread safe at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think Singletons are far better than Static classes

Below is Answers to your question serially :

1) No , It totally depends upon your requirements  but yes static classes are faster but also allows more bugs into your project

2) Yes sometimes as long as its not affecting your private data members and make your data insecure

3) Using Singletons as it provides more OO funtionalities and thus increase performance

Here is a great reference article for you :

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/03/difference-between-singleton-pattern-vs-static-class-java.html